# AngularJs - if() condition in a directive observe function not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to resize a CSS style based on a button click. The idea is to show/hide content based on the click with animation. There was some existing code with DOM & Javascript that was written to do this, but now we need to move it into AngularJS (which I am VERY new to).

After much trial and error, I've settle on using ng-if to show/hide content but I still need to set the height for the CSS Style background to apply properly to the expanded content(The content's length is dynamic in the production application).

So, to set the "max-height", I am trying to toggle a variable between true and false on button click which is then sent to a "toggleHeight" directive. Based on the value the directive is supposed to set maxHeight to either scrollheight or null.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BaseController">
  <div ng-init "expandBox=false">
    <button ng-click="expandBox=!expandBox">Test</button>
  <br/>
    <div class="testCss" toggle-height="{{expandBox}}">
    Lorem ipsum ......
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.content = 'World';
})
.directive("toggleHeight",function(){
    return {
        restrict :"A",
        scope : {
            toggleHeight : "@"
        },
        link : function(scope,element,attrs){
           attrs.$observe("toggleHeight", function(value) {
               console.log("Value:",value);
               if(value) {
                   element[0].style.maxHeight=element[0].scrollHeight+"px";
                   console.log("height set to scrollHeight. value:",value);
               } else {
                   element[0].style.maxHeight="100px";
                   console.log("height is reset. value:",value);
               }
            })
         }
    };
});
```

CSS:

```
 .testCss {
   color:white;
   background-color: black;
   max-height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

But irrespective of the "toggleHeight"value, the value always gets set to the scrollHeight. Printing the value the variable inside the if-else shows that its been changed, but the code executed is always from the "true" block.

Since am new, it seems like I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: Be aware that in JavaScript, the string `"false"` evaluates as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that in JavaScript, the string `"false"` evaluates as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Expression interpolation with curly brackets (`{{ }}`) converts boolean values to string values.

Avoid using interpolation for values other than strings:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="BaseController">
  <div ng-init "expandBox=false">
    <button ng-click="expandBox=!expandBox">Test</button>
  <br/>
    ̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶=̶"̶t̶e̶s̶t̶C̶s̶s̶"̶ ̶t̶o̶g̶g̶l̶e̶-̶h̶e̶i̶g̶h̶t̶=̶"̶{̶{̶e̶x̶p̶a̶n̶d̶B̶o̶x̶}̶}̶"̶
    <div class="testCss" toggle-height="expandBox">
    Lorem ipsum ......
```

Instead use a watcher that evaluates the expression:

```
app.directive("toggleHeight",function(){
    return {
        restrict :"A",
        //scope : {
        //    toggleHeight : "@"
        //},
        scope: false,
        link : function(scope,element,attrs){
           ̶a̶t̶t̶r̶s̶.̶$̶o̶b̶s̶e̶r̶v̶e̶(̶"̶t̶o̶g̶g̶l̶e̶H̶e̶i̶g̶h̶t̶"̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶
           scope.$watch(attrs.toggleHeight, function(value) {
               console.log("Value:",value);
               if(value) {
                   element[0].style.maxHeight=element[0].scrollHeight+"px";
                   console.log("height set to scrollHeight. value:",value);
               } else {
                   element[0].style.maxHeight="100px";
                   console.log("height is reset. value:",value);
               }
            })
         }
    };
});
```

Also the directive does not need an isolate scope.

Comment: Perfect! This works and thanks for the clear explanation. I've accepted the answer but am curious about the switch to $watch, because most of the documentation seems to suggest using to $observe for attribute directive values. Am confused now about how to choose between the two.

Comment: Very few of the core AngularJS directives use $observe. I don't know who teaches it, but they should tell their students one of the pitfalls is that it only returns strings.